# Hashtable not properly updating in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

so I created a weekly reboot script.  I read an AD Group and then reboot a bunch of computers on the weekend.  I then send a HTML result via e-mail with the logs.  I tested this by adding a few down computers to the list.  It only returns the LAST unpingable computer.  Can someone tell me why?  I need a second set of eyes.  Ive done this type of hashtable before and it worked just fine.

```
$RBList = (Get-QADGroupMember prv_RebootSchedule | Sort Name | Select -expand Name)
foreach($PC in $RBList){
$datetime = Get-Date            
ping -n 2 $PC >$null
if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
shutdown /r /f /m \\$PC /d p:1:1 /t 600 /c "Weekly Reboot - Maintnence scheduled!"
write-host "$pc is rebooting"
$result = "Success"
} else {
Write-host "$pc has error adding to table"
$Result = "Error - Check"
}
$table = [ordered]@{
Workstation = $pc
Result = $result
Time = $datetime
} 
}
$html =  [PSCustomObject]$table | convertto-html -CssUri "C:\scripts\automatedreboot\table.css"         
send-mailmessage -to "email@email.com" -from "Automated Reboot<no-reply@email.com>" -subject "Automated Reboot Error Log" -BodyAsHtml "$html" -smtpserver smtp.email.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$RBList = (Get-QADGroupMember prv_RebootSchedule | Sort Name | Select -expand Name)
$table = @()

foreach($PC in $RBList)
{
    $obj = "" | select Workstation, Result, Time
    $datetime = Get-Date            
    ping -n 2 $PC >$null
    if($lastexitcode -eq 0)
    {
        #shutdown /r /f /m \\$PC /d p:1:1 /t 600 /c "Weekly Reboot - Maintnence scheduled!"
        write-host "$pc is rebooting"
        $result = "Success"
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-host "$pc has error adding to table"
        $Result = "Error - Check"
    }

$obj.Workstation = $pc
$obj.Result = $result
$obj.Time = $datetime

$table += $obj    
}

$html = $table | convertto-html -Property name, value -as table
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked!  $html didn't return anything but when i used my original it did show me ALL the results.  Thanks!

Comment: Cam you explain this part? $table += $obj.  I have a general understanding of what you did but whats that line do exactly?

Comment: @Patrick In the firsts line $table is declared as an array. the line you talk is like $table = $table + $obj and it adds in the array the current value of custom $obj. I hope I have been almolst clear :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense!  One more question and I'm done.  I've been asked to exclude the Successful reboots.  How would I make the array NOT include those?  Would I pipe in a | Select Result -exclude "Sucess"?

Comment: I figured it out by adding this: | Where Result -ne "Success" |

Answer (score 2):

Same idea (as CB), but a little different implementation:

```
$RBList = (Get-QADGroupMember prv_RebootSchedule | Sort Name | Select -expand Name)

$EmailParams = @{
 to         = 'email@email.com' 
 from       = 'Automated Reboot<no-reply@email.com>' 
 subject    = 'Automated Reboot Error Log' 
 BodyAsHtml =  $true
 smtpserver = 'smtp.email.com'
 }

$table = 
   foreach($PC in $RBList){
     $datetime = Get-Date            
     ping -n 2 $PC >$null

     if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
       shutdown /r /f /m \\$PC /d p:1:1 /t 600 /c "Weekly Reboot - Maintnence scheduled!"
       write-host "$pc is rebooting"
       $result = "Success"

       } else {
         Write-host "$pc has error adding to table"
         $Result = "Error - Check"
       }

   [PSCustomObject]@{
                      Workstation = $pc
                      Result      = $result
                      Time        = $datetime
                     } 
  } 

$html = $table | convertto-html -CssUri "C:\scripts\automatedreboot\table.css"


Send-MailMessage @EmailParams -Body $html
```